# Creating a Structure from a string in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic, structure

I've seen a lot of questions asked about instantiating classes from a string but have been unable to find any information on creating a structure the same way.

I have a class which contains a structure like so:

```
Public Structure callDetails
    Public GUID As Guid
    Public ringTime as Date
    Public CBN As String
```

etc.

All I really want to do is get the field names from the structure. I don't care to manipulate the data in the fields.

So far I can get pretty close with this.

```
        callDetails callTableDef= new callDetails();

        Type tableType = callTableDef.GetType();

        object tableStruct = (object)Activator.CreateInstance(tableType);
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fields = tableType.GetFields();
        foreach (System.Reflection.FieldInfo field in fields)
        Debug.WriteLine(field.Name + " = " + field.GetValue(tableStruct));
```

However, I still need to create an instance of the structure with the actual name. I want to be able to pass in a string like this:

```
Type tableType = System.Type.GetType("callDetails");
```

When I do that I get an ArgumentNullException from Activator.CreateInstance()

Isn't getType supposed to look up the value passed to it as a string and return the type?

I'm new to C# having programmed mostly in Java until this project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must qualify the type name with its namespace:

```
Type tableType = System.Type.GetType("mynamespace.callDetails");
```

If it's in a different assembly, you need the assembly qualified name. Details can by found [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx). With just the type name as you have, it won't be able to resolve and will return `null`, hence your argument null exception.

Answer (score 1):

If the struct or class is accessible, meaning you have a reference to it, it's better to use `GetType`, because that takes the struct/class instead of a string. This means it'll fail at compile time when there's an error, and also gives you better refactor possibilities

```
Type tableType = GetType(callDetails)
```

In C#:

```
Type tableType = typeof(callDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks David,

That MSDN reference was exactly what I needed. I tried qualifying it as many ways as I knew how. The class was in a different assembly. I tried

```
Type tableType = System.Type.GetType("CommonTables.callDetails");
```

to no effect.

For others looking up this question here's what I had to do:

After writing the following to debug:

```
Debug.WriteLine("DEBUG ASSEMBLY QUALIFIED NAME= " + callTableDef.GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName.ToString());
```

it gave me this
 as the assembly qualified name.

```
CommonTables.callDetails, callDetails, Version=3.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

And that's the string I had to use in the getType() method. just the assembly.classname didn't work.